# First mean value theorem for integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration

[image]

Hello! The above picture is an excerpt from Zorich's book. I was able to solve part a) but do not know how to attack part b).

Parts a) and b) are very similar to  the theorem from this book which I'll attach below. In this theorem in part a) the infimum and supremum are taken over open interval $(a,b)$. In part b) if we take $g(x)\equiv 1$ then there is a point $\xi$ belongs to $[a,b]$ but in our problem this point should in $(a,b)$.

I guess part b) can be deduced somehow from part a) but I do not know how to do it. I'd be very thankful for any help!

[image]

Comment: Well, it sounds like you have a solid approach to follow. In what situation does it turn out that $\xi=a$ or $\xi=b$? But you certainly can deduce the result from part a. What is the main hypothesis you're not paying enough attention to?

Comment: If you've already gotten the first one, the second follows from the intermediate value theorem for continuous functions.

Comment: @Jose27, really? Is there any connection between a) and b)?

Comment: Yep. Once you know $\mu\in [m,M]$, notice that $f$ being continuous on $[a,b]$ means that the values $m$ and $M$ are attained at some points. Then there exists $x_0$ such that $\mu=f(x_0)$ by the IVT (though you might have to tweak it a bit to ensure that $x_0\in ]a,b[$).

Comment: Or you can go the safe route with the mean value theorem for derivatives applied to a well-chosen function.

Comment: @Jose27, about your second comment. Yes I know that this result can obtained from MVT applied to integral where the upper limit of integration is some variable. But in Zorich's book this result comes in the next chapter. So I would prefer to solve using first method.

Comment: @Jose27, I still do not see the connection between b) and a). Maybe you can show the solution as a separate answer, please? I will appreciate your help!

Comment: You can also argue by contradiction. Assume $f$ never takes the value $\mu$ then all its values are greater than $\mu$ (or all the values of $f$ are less than $\mu$). Then the integral will be greater (or less) than $\mu(b-a) $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By basic properties of integrals, we have
$$
m\leq \dfrac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)\, dx \leq M.
$$
On the other hand, by continuity of $f$ on $[a,b]$, there exist $x_m, x_M\in [a,b]$ such that $f(x_m)=m$ and $f(x_M)=M$. Therefore
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
f(x_m)\leq \dfrac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)\, dx \leq f(x_M).
\end{equation}
If $m=M$ then $f$ is constant and so any $\xi\in ]a,b[$ will do, so we assume $m<M$. In this case we can see that both inequalities in (1) are strict (for instance consider $f(x)-m\geq 0$, and if the integral of this is zero then $f\equiv m$ which is a contradiction). Assume that $x_m<x_M$ (if the opposite is true change the interval $]x_m, x_M[$ for $]x_M,x_m[$ below), then by the intermediate value theorem, and (1) with the strict inequalities, there exists $\xi\in ]x_m,x_M[$ such that
$$
f(\xi)= \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)\, dx.
$$
This is what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution! Actually my ideas were almost the same but I did not get why the inequalities should be strict. And we see that $\xi \in (x_m,x_M)$ because inequalities are strict, right? Because $\xi$ cannot be equal to one of the endpoints.

Comment: @ZFR: Yes, you're correct. $\xi$ being one of the endpoints means that the integral average is equal to either the min or the max, which we already ruled out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! +1

Comment: I was wondering can we conclude that $\xi\in(a,b)$ for equation (6.26) (see the above picture)?